# flutter pushNamedAndRemoveUntil works on android but not on iOS

Tags: flutter

The following code works on android but not on iOS

```
Navigator.of(context)
    .pushNamedAndRemoveUntil('/login', (Route<dynamic> route) => false);
```

Any idea, solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can use pushAndRemoveUntil. It takes class. It is working on my project. For example;

```
Navigator.of(context).pushAndRemoveUntil(
             CupertinoPageRoute(
                   builder: (context) => Login()),
                   (_) => false,);
```